# Mean width of a simplex as one edge becomes longer

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, geometric-probability

Consider an edge $e$ of a simplex $C$. If we increase the length of $e$ while keeping the length of other edges constant, the width of $C$ increases in some directions and decreases in other directions. Does the [mean width](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mean_width) of $C$ increase? The answer is yes for triangles, since the mean width of a triangle is proportional to its perimeter. What about simplexes of higher dimension?

Comment: This is vague as stated, but one precise question is: If we pick a side, fix its midpoint, move the two vertices on that side further away from each other,  and fix all other vertices, can the mean width increase in that process?

Comment: Your question is different from mine : the lengths of other edges change in the process. Up to isomorphism, the matrice of distances between vertices uniquely determines a simplex, and my question is precise.

Comment: I'd find that question more clearly asked as: "If two simplices have the same graphs of distances between vertices, with the exception of one edge that differs between them, can the simplex with the larger edge have smaller mean width?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mean width is monotone with respect to the length of any edge of a tetrahedron. This follows from these two facts:

1. The mean width of a 3-dimensional polyhedron is proportional to $\sum_i \ell_i \theta_i$, where $\ell_i$ are the edge lengths and $\theta_i$ are the exterior dihedral angles.
2. The Schlaefli formula: $\frac{\partial}{\partial\ell_i}\sum_j \ell_j \theta_j = \theta_i$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference on 1.?

Comment: Usually this is stated in a broader context of quermassintegrals: the average volume of projections to $k$-dimensional linear subspaces is proportional to a certain mixed volume, which is a coefficient in the Steiner formula. I can mention two books: Santalo, Integral geometry and geometric probability, and Schneider, Convex bodies: the Brunn-Minkowski theory.